# QTCreator designer widget need hide QWidget properties

Tags: c++, qt, widget, components, qwidget

I ve implemented non QWidget based Control.  Works fine, but I need to make a component without QWidget properties.

Something like QVBoxLayout.
Is there some way to hide propeties of QWidget?

Comment: can you explain more about what you need exactly? your question is a little bit unclear.

Comment: If you look at object property  inspector of each plugin (CheckBox,Label,...) you can see that they have QWidget properties . Because they inherit Qwidget. But VLayout HLayout don't. So I have QObject based ui component. Hence I can't return Qwidget pointer.